# Compare variables in Django Templates

Tags: django, templates, variables, compare

I have two variables in my **Django** template file

like

> {{orderitem.value.id}}

and `

> {{ orderitem.order.id }}

I need to show some **data** if they are **equal** but i don’t know how to **compare** variables in html files .

please suggest.

Comment: Did you try this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-ifequal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [ifequal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal) tag to compare variables in templates:

sample:

```
{% ifequal orderitem.value.id orderitem.order.id %}
    <p>are equals!<p/>
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: removed in v4.0